# On finding adjoint of transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $v,w\in V$ be fixed vectors. Define $T(u)=(u,v)w$.  How to find the adjoint mapping $T^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of adjoint:
$(Tu, z) = (u, T^*z)$

So, for all $u, z \in V$:

$(Tu, z) = ( (u,v)w, z ) = (u,v) \cdot (w,z) = (u, \overline{(w,z)}v)
= (u, (z, w) v)$

So, $T^*(z) = (z,w)v$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $( (u,v)w, z ) = (u,v) \cdot (w,z)$?

Comment: (u,v) is just a scalar. Since the inner product is linear in the first slot, you can pull it out of the inner product.